# Combine 2 JavaScript into 1

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a clean up for a Webscrape.

This is my current script.

```
var cleanup = function(results) {
 $.each(results, function(){
  this.values[0] = this.values[0].replace("Submission date: ", 
  "").split(" ")[0];
    this.values[1] = this.values[1].replace("Case number: ", "");
 });
  return results;  
  };
```

I've then found out that I need to add

```
  var d = "2010-10-30".slice(0, 10).split('-');   
  d[1] +'/'+ d[2] +'/'+ d[0]; // 10/30/2010
```

in order to change the way the data is written. My current output is `YYYY-MM-DD` that needs to be `MM/DD/YYYY`

I'm having difficulties combining the 2 scripts to get the desired functions.

Comment: I doubt that you need to add this particular code with a _fixed_ date? So presumably you want to access a date value from somewhere else - variable? Form field? Your question is pretty much unanswerable right now, because it lacks context. Please go read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: How are those two code snippets related?

Comment: The seconde code snippet is from a previous question about converting the date i get in my scrape output - Any other ideas are welcome

Comment: The line `d[1] +'/'+ d[2] +'/'+ d[0];` doesn't do anything with the concatenated date. You need to assign it to another variable.

Comment: Does the date that you're splitting up come from something in the `results` array?

Comment: It's a Table that i scrape via a Extension in Chrome - i can then add Javascript to clean up the scrape results before its download in .xlsx   - the date is in the first row

Comment: What does that have to do with my question? Where does the date `2010-10-30` in the second piece of code come from? Is it related to the array that you're using in `$.each()` or is it just something else you have to clean up?

Comment: Thats my fault - the date is from the snippet that i took. the date is not fixed. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Is `this.values[0]` the property in question? You are removing `Submission date: ` from that, so does that the field contain a date value in the form `YYYY-MM-DD` now? (Then it would probably be as simple as `var d = this.values[0].slice(0, 10).split('-'); this.values[0] = d[1] +'/'+ d[2] +'/'+ d[0];` inserted into the loop at the appropriate position.)

Comment: @04FS if you ever come to Denmark the beers are on me! THANK YOU! Worked like a charm

Comment: Okay, Iet me add this as an answer then ... done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.values[0]` is the property in question and contains a date value in the form YYYY-MM-DD now (after the line that removed the `Submission date:` text), then it should be as simple as this:

```
 // take the date value from the field & split it
 var d = this.values[0].slice(0, 10).split('-');
 // assign the parts in new order and concatenated with the separator / back to the field
 this.values[0] = d[1] +'/'+ d[2] +'/'+ d[0];
```